# Center align image inside div horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, image, css

I currently have a `header` div and inside of it, I have `header-top` and `header-bottom`. I am trying to place my logo on the `top-header` and align it vertically and horizontally. The logo aligns horizontally but vertically, it pushes aligns according to the `body` it seems and it brings the header down 20px. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="big-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header-top">
                <img src="img/main-logo.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="header-bottom">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(237, 237, 237, 1);
}

#header-top {
    height: 130px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

#header-top img {
    height: 90px;
    width: 255px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#header-bottom {
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

This is what I get

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion. Could be wrong.

```
    <div id="header-top">
        <center>
            <img src="img/main-logo.png" />
        </center>
    </div>
```

If wrong, try aligning the div as so.

Edit:
If all else fails, edit image, and offset it to desired alignment

Comment: I tried the `center` tag and it centered the image horizontally. In my css, I added `margin-top` of 20px to the image. This worked. Is there a reason why this worked and my way didn't? Thank you.

Comment: Possibly <div id="big-wrapper"> ? You didn't specify this within your CSS, perhaps something broke there.

Comment: Ohh I see, you're right. Something must have gone wrong there. I will apply your method for now and fix that later. Thank you! :)

Comment: <center> tag is sort of deprecated now... not supported in HTML5 now (refer http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)... I tried a `flexbox` solution and posted the answer here